# docker containers are not connecting through ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

im trying to run two containers:

```
 A:
    image: myImage:e2e
    ports:
      - "5100:80"
    volumes:
    - ../myui-sources/:/app
    command: bash -c "npm run json-server" # this will run on port 5100 -- output: 'API started! listening to port!: 5100'

  B:
    build:
      context: ../myui-sources/e2e/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile  # 'here im copying files and running a yarn install'
    depends_on:
      - A
    volumes:
      - ../myui-sources/:/app
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    command:  bash -c "yarn e2e" # this will try to connect with container A, output: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5100'
```

container B in port 4200 needs to interact with container A in localhost:5100,
i added the ports on each container but with not result, what im doing wrong?, what I need to change?, I'm new to docker, thank you in advance!

when im running the command yarn e2e i have the following:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
[33mB_1  |[0m $ npx cucumber-js
[33mB_1  |[0m Failures:
[33mB_1  |[0m 
[33mB_1  |[0m 1) Scenario: The contents of the root folder should be displayed in the Table View # test/features/poc.feature:11
[33mB_1  |[0m    ✖ Before # test/hooks/api.hooks.ts:4
[33mB_1  |[0m        Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5100
```

Comment: **ports: - "5100:80"** You are mapping the host port with the container port HOST:CONTAINER, host: 5100, container: 80. Internally, the container is using the port 80. So, try to connect using the port 80. And use the container name, the dns should resolve the address for you.

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation discusses this setup further.

Comment: In order for the containers to communicate through **localhost** they should be configured to use the **host** network mode which means all ports of the two containers will be shared with the host. And in this scenario you cannot have port mappings (e.g 5100:80. There's only the port 5100 shared between container A, the host and container B). The default (and recommended) network mode is **bridge** which works as @a_e explained. Another solution may be to use Kubernetes and to place both containers in the same pod. Containers from the same pod communicate through **localhost:{internalPort}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers that are on the same network connect to eachother directly by using the service name as the hostname. The default for `docker-compose` is to add all services to a network.

So to connect to `A` from `B` you would use `A` as the hostname, and then the actual port the container is using, in your case `80`. So `A:80`.

Comment: thank you for your answer @super, how can i create the network for this docker-compose? thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You don't need to. `docker-compose` does that for you automatically. If you need to chose the network name to use together with other docker containers have a look at their documentation. It covers that in quite some detail.